# Whats the easiset way to integrate a CSS Library into WordPress

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4, tailwind-css

I am looking for an easy quick best way to get Bootstrap or Tailwind CSS working inside my WordPress to help stayle pages and posts.

Is there a plugin to install or code snippet to drop inside functions.php - I am still learning Web Dev and really green at it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [`wp_enqueue_scripts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) is your friend. Or, just drop it in `header.php` (although enqueuing is the preferred method).

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work for TailwindCSS: `<?php  function add_theme_codes() {   wp_enqueue_style( ‘style’, ‘https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css’);  }  add_action( ‘wp_enqueue_scripts’, ‘add_theme_codes’ );  ?>`

Comment: Where are you adding that code? And also, it appears you are using "smart" quotes. Those need to be changed to regular quotes `'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank-you and thanks to some code I found elsewehere, I was also able to get it enqueued via a WordPress Plugin called Code Snippets but it would have also worked in the functions.php file as well.

```
<?php
function pwwp_enqueue_my_scripts() {
    // jQuery is stated as a dependancy of bootstrap-js - it will be loaded by WordPress before the BS scripts 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', '//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), true); // all the bootstrap javascript goodness
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pwwp_enqueue_my_scripts');

function pwwp_enqueue_my_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', '//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

    // this will add the stylesheet from it's default theme location if your theme doesn't already
    //wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pwwp_enqueue_my_styles');
?>
```

And here is the one used for TailwindCSS

```
<?php
    function pwwp_enqueue_my_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', '//unpkg.com/tailwindcss@2.1.2/dist/tailwind.min.css' );

    // this will add the stylesheet from it's default theme location if your theme doesn't already
    //wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pwwp_enqueue_my_styles');
?>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the above two peices of code? Why did you use "bootstrap" in the third line of the second part?